# Dashboard on IBM Watson Studio for GDP Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, ibm-watson, watson-studio

I am working with IBM Watson studio and am a beginner, How can I create a dashboard in Watson Studio using Python? I need some help, thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you need a guide or tutorial, please see [help/on-topic], [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You would use a Python notebook to prepare your data, i.e. create data assets in your project suitable for dashboarding, with reduced volumes.
Then the easiest way to create a dashboard is to use the `Cognos Dashboard Embedded` (CDE) service.